# No exception for queries during Cassandra connection drop

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

In our SpringData Cassandra application, when connection to data store, connection retires happen as

```
2018-04-25T10:30:00.677+0000,ERROR,[Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 1000 milliseconds
2018-04-25T10:30:01.678+0000,ERROR,[Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 2000 milliseconds
2018-04-25T10:30:03.679+0000,ERROR,[Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 4000 milliseconds
2018-04-25T10:30:07.679+0000,ERROR,[Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 8000 milliseconds
```

Question 1: Is it possible to change the scheduling interval?

Question 2: When connection is being retried, if a query is executed from spring data, an empty response is sent instead of an exception, would it be possible to generate an exception if the data store is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

For #1:
You need to add ReconnectionPolicy to your cluster definiton, see documentation here:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.5/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/ReconnectionPolicy.html

In context.xml:

```
<bean id="reconnectionPolicy"
    class="com.datastax.driver.core.policies.ConstantReconnectionPolicy">
    <constructor-arg name="constantDelayMs"
        value="${cluster.reconnection.delayMillis}" />
</bean>
<cassandra:cluster id="globalCassandraCluster"
                contact-points="${cassandra.contactpoints}"
                port="${cassandra.port}"
                username="${cassandra.username}"
                password="${cassandra.password}"
                compression="LZ4"
                max-queue-size="256"
                reconnection-policy-ref="reconnectionPolicy">
 <cassandra:socket-options read-timeout-millis="${cassandra.socketReadTimeout}"/>
```

or:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
.addContactPoints("127.0.0.1")
.withPort(9142)
.withCredentials(username, password)
.withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(DELAY_IN_MS))
.build();
Session session = cluster.connect();
```

For #2:
could you maybe add some more details on this? It would be helpful to see your code and the reply you receive.